# Place Text over a full screen video

Tags: text, html5-video

Working on a little self project and having some trouble getting text placed on top of my background video.

At present, the code is sitting as follows:

```
<div class="video_container">
    <div class="contentContainer">
        <div class="skipButton">
            <h1>Skip</h1>
        </div>

        <video id="tgVideo" autoplay loop>
            <source src="videos/bgvidm4v.m4v" preload="none">
        </video>

    </div>
</div>
```

I am making the video full screen and keep this way when displaying on different size monitors by using the following JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var vid = $('video');
  var vid_w_orig = 1280;
  var vid_h_orig = 720;

  // re-scale image when window resizes
  $(window).resize(function () {
    //Get the parent element size
    var container_w = vid.parent().width();
    var container_h = vid.parent().height();

    //Use largest scale factor of horizontal/vertical
    var scale_w = container_w / vid_w_orig;
    var scale_h = container_h / vid_h_orig;
    var scale = scale_w > scale_h ? scale_w : scale_h;

    //Scale the video to fit any size screen
    vid.width(scale * vid_w_orig);
    vid.height(scale * vid_h_orig);
  });

  //Trigger re-scale of the video on pageload
  $(window).trigger('resize');

});
```

This combination is working flawlessly for me so far. Only issue is getting the video to run on Android/iOS, but I think that's a limitation of the device.

What I am in need of is adding a piece of text for now that a user can click on to bring them away from the video. I am adding the href to the button after I get the text to display on top of the video.

I have found some tutorials online and have tried the below

```
.video_container .contentContainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    z-index:999;
}

.video_container .contentContainer .skipButton {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.video_container .contentContainer .skipButton h1 {
    color:#FFF;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

This is working for the most part, where I can see the text for a split second before it disappears behind the video.

Anyone have any tips for me?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the whole container to `z-index: 999`, this element `.contentContainer` contains also the video element. So I would put z-index only on the text containers alone with non-static position in order z-index to take effect.

```
.video_container .contentContainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    z-index:999; // not needed
}

.video_container .contentContainer .skipButton {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.video_container .contentContainer .skipButton h1 {
    color:#FFF;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the assistance on this! Got sorted with the above.

Comment: Glad if I could help ;)